# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE When trying to access phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

When accessing http://domain.com/phpmyadmin

I get the following error (this one is in chrome, but it is not working in any other browser either):

```
No data received
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

When trying to access, apache's error log shows:

```
apache2: /build/buildd/xcache-1.3.2/stack.c:47: xc_stack_count: Assertion      `stack != ((void *)0)' failed.
[Sat Apr 18 23:41:18 2015] [notice] child pid 31027 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

All worked well a week ago, can't figure out what went wrong.

Rebooted, reinstalled, reconfiugured phpmyadmin, nothing works :(

Working under Ubuntu 10.04,

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was facing same error. Fixed it by removing a php module: `php5-xcache`

Answer (score 2):

Received same error in browser.

Apache's error_log shows:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libnsssysinit.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure
```

Fixed by restarting Apache via stop and start (`apachectl restart` is not sufficient).